# loading the content of a text file in a textarea using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a `textarea`. I want to load the content of text file and fill that content into the `textarea`.

Code is as below but nothing happens.

```
   $('#contenu-trame-cr').load('http://gravelines-si.fr/TrameCR.txt', function (data) {
    $(this).text(data);
});
```

Note that the id of my `textzarea` is `contenu-trame-cr`

Answer (score 1):

if "data" object is populated successfully you might want to try using .val(data) instead of .text(data) when working with textarea

edited:
from your path it should go something like:

```
$('#contenu-trame-cr').load('/SDIN/SDINAccueil/Accueil/tools/TrameCR.txt', function (data) {
   $(this).val(data);
});
```

IMHO it should work if you manage to get the correct path to the file. So play around with it if this sample does not work.

What platform are you using? are you writing a ASP MVC website, php?

Don't forget, that .Load is a request which means it could only be served by a server. If you are simply running an html file in the browser it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: which is the server that serves the request to http://gravelines-si.fr/TrameCR.txt? Are you getting a cross-site-scripting error or any type of error? what does it say in the console? Have you debugged to see if the function is being called? what is the value (if any) of "data" ?

Comment: gravelines-si.fr/TrameCR.txt is just an example to do my test but i think that it's the reason why is not working.
in fact i have the text file in my local folder but i don't know how to write its route ! i'm working with symfony and i'm really a noob at it

Comment: if its in your local folder a simple "/[filename.extension]" should work.

Comment: I did replace the 'gravelines-si.fr/TrameCR.txt' by my file and it displayed a code of a page